# Properly insert ethernet cable into RJ-45 wall port?

Tags: networking, ethernet, switch, rj-45

This has always puzzled me and made me wonder if there is a better way of accomplishing such a simple task. Many might have come across one variant of an Ethernet wall port with a plastic cover over the top, supposedly because of children. Yes, there is a little groove at the bottom of this little plastic window which I guess your nail can get under and lift. Also, I theorize, maybe, that you use the actual Ethernet jack you want to insert to open and lift the little window since that takes your stump of a finger out of the equation. Have I just been doing this wrong for years or is there an actual standardized way of going about this? This all seems too finicky to be right.

EDIT: Here's a picture, I see they are mostly used in school environments.
[image: Picture] 
[image: Picture]

Comment: Photos? (Not many childproof wall ports around here.)

Comment: Yeah, I would like to see this picture as well... I have worked in this industry for 25 years and i could count the number of Ethernet jacks I have seen with some kind of "door" on one hand, on the other hand I have seen numerous voice jacks but most of them are over 10 years old.

Comment: @acejavelin http://i.stack.imgur.com/h57pL.jpg

Comment: @user4191887 Again, I have been in the VoIP, data networking, cabling, and telephony industry for over 25 years... I have done wiring jobs in dozens, perhaps well over a hundred, of schools, universities, libraries, etc. and I have never seen these implemented or even spec'd for a job. Perhaps it is your locality, or mine, but I don't think these are standard.

Comment: @acejavelin Well I live in the UK and I think it may be a standard here if that helps at all.

Comment: I've never seen the other sort in a office environment ever. I always figured the dust covers were standard and intuitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just use the jack to push the plug up,

[image],

having the cable at an angle. The green area is angled to 'lead' the cable in

then tilt it down and in, and line up the top of the connector with the green area and push it up and in.

[image: ![![enter image description here]

Comment: I thought so, though in all my years, most plates I've come across have either been worn or old since it takes a few minutes just to keep the damn thing open.